# php. if conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

This seems simple but I don't know why it doe snot work.

I need to write an if statement that

```
 first, checks if it is numeric  

 second, if it is not between 1 and 10, issue errorA

 third, if it is not between 20 and 30, issue errorB

 fourth, it is not a number, issue errorC
```

If is not numeric and satisfies all the ranges, added to the database.

anyways, I am not sure about the if and while combination to satisfy this....

So far I have,

if numeric and satisfies ranges, add to database
else, issue errorC

How can I filter for error A and B?

```
if ( isset [some code...]) {

    $a = ...;
    $b = ...);
    $c = ...;

    if (preg_match('/^\d+$/',$b) && preg_match('/^\d+$/',$c) &&
        ((1 <= $b && 10 >= $b)) && ((20 <= $c && 30 >= $c))) {

        $sql = "INSERT [some code...]

        mysql_query($sql);

        $_SESSION['success'] = $_POST['success'];
        header('Location: index.php') ;
        return;

    } else {

        $_SESSION['error'] = $_POST['error'];
        header('Location: index.php') ;
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should show some code.

Comment: this sounds like homework? though you may want to look at is_numeric, <, > and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: How can it be between 1 and 10 ***and*** 10 and 20?!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/^\d+$/',$b) && preg_match('/^\d+$/',$c)) {
    if (($b >= 1 && $b <= 10) && ($c >= 20 && $c <= 30)) {
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "not in range";
    }
} else {
  echo "not a number";
}
```